For my training loss vs validation loss plot, why does my validation loss abruptly end?
I'm trying to make a chatbot, but whenever I try to plot my training loss vs validation loss, my validation loss will suddenly end.Training loss vs Validation loss
This was the code that I used for the training argument. I'm not sure what I can change to fix this issue.
train_testvalid = tokenized_datasets.train_test_split(test_size=0.5)
train_dataset = train_testvalid["train"]
eval_dataset = train_testvalid["test"]

data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',
    num_train_epochs=50,
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    warmup_steps=1000,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir='./logs',
    logging_steps=10,  # Log more frequently
    evaluation_strategy="steps",  # Evaluate periodically
    eval_steps=100,  # Adjust evaluation frequency (every 100 steps)
    save_steps=1000,  # Save checkpoints every 1000 steps
    learning_rate=5e-5,
    max_steps=-1,
)



device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', num_labels=len(set(labels)))
model.to(device)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
)


